# SailsJS - Nodejs Https-Request. Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm new to Sails.js and I was trying to make a filter to authorize using a Bearer token which come from a higher server, a gatekeeper which is responsable  to do the OAuth2 authentication from GitHub API. The services streams works well. I'm already aware of Passport.js but I'm trying to implement this on my own. I came with a `policy` which looks like:

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
  var httpsExec = require('https');
  if (req.headers.authorization) {
    var parts = req.headers.authorization.split(' ');
    if (parts.length == 2) {
      var tokenType = parts[0]
        , credentials = parts[1];
      if (/^Bearer$/i.test(tokenType) || /^bearer$/i.test(tokenType)) {
        httpsExec.request({
          host: 'api.github.com',
          post: 443,
          path: '/user',
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {'Authorization': 'token ' + credentials, 'User-Agent': 'curly'}
        }, function (response) {
          var responseData = '';
          response.setEncoding('utf8');

          response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            responseData += chunk;
          });

          response.once('error', function (err) {
              next(err);
          });

          response.on('end', function () {
            try {
              req.options.user = JSON.parse(responseData);
              next();
            } catch (e) {
              res.send(401, {error: e});
            }
          });
        }).end();
      } else {
        console.err("The token is not a Bearer");
        res.send(401)
      }
    }
  } else {
    res.send(401, {error: "Full authentication is necessary to access this resource"})
  }

};
```

The policy is called once I hit the controller route but it throws a `_http_outgoing.js:335
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
          ^
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

And the process is terminate.

The problem I think is the `next()` and the `returns` I tried everywhere I think, to put the `next()` call, but still gives me this error, if I remove then I lock the request on the policy.

**EDIT**

I did a simple sample of policy where I just set some property on req.options.values and happened the same problem, so maybe could be an issue with `req.options.requestData = JSON.parse(responseData);` ? How else could I set a property to send to controller ?

Comment: try removing end() from code.

Comment: @user111111111 if I remove, it throws:
```events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: socket hang up
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
          response.once('error', function (err) {
               next(err);
          });

          response.on('end', function () {
            try {
              req.options.user = JSON.parse(responseData);
              next();
            } catch (e) {
              res.send(401, {error: e});
            }
          });
```

both are getting executed.to check console.log("something") in error to see if there is error.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you're trying to modify the request and response together or modify one of them twice.

In your code, I think the callback is being called twice and you are also modifying the response at the same time. Check the lines where you're calling callback "next()". You'll find your issue.

Comment: I found the issue on the controller and not on the policy, since the most times I invoke the callback `next()` is to proceed the method on a if/else or try/catch on the begining of controller method these lines 
` var artifact = req.body.artifact;`
  `if (!artifact) res.badRequest({error: "Artifact must be not null or empty!"});`
When artifact is not on the body and must return bad request but sometimes it crashs into the exception

Comment: Give **req.param("key")** a shot.

So if you want to get artifact, then try **req.param("artifact")** and use it like this

if (req.param("artifact")) {
}